# Function needs to be made before calling it, but variable has to be assigned before referenced

Tags: python, function, variables, tkinter, integer

the get age function needs y

```
import math
import os
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("DOG AGE CALCULATOR!!")


#define function to convert x.0 to x
def formatNumber(num):
  if num % 1 == 0:
    return int(num)
  else:
    return num
#print menu

def getAge():
    # Convert y
    if(y == 1):
        dy = int(15)
    elif(y == 2):
        dy = int(24)
    elif(y > 2):
        dy = int(((y-2)*5)+24)
    else:
        p = 2

    #convert m
    if(y == 0):
        dm = float(m*1.25)
    elif(y == 1):
        dm = float(m*0.75)
    elif(y > 1):
        dm =  float(m*(5/12))
    else:
        p = 2

    #add excess months to years
    if(dm > 12):
        dm = dm//12
        y = y+(dm%12)

    #add dog years and months
    dogym = float(dy+dm)
    #seperate dog month and year
    dogmonth, dogyears =  math.modf(dogym)
    dogmonths = dogmonth*12
    #formatting dog year and month
    dogmonths = formatNumber(dogmonths)
    dogyears = formatNumber(dogyears)
    dogyearstr = str("{} Dog Years".format(dogyears))
    dogmonthstr = str("{} Dog Months".format(dogmonths))
    for widget in frame.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()
    ylabel = Label(root, text=dogyearstr)
    mlabel = Label(root, text=dogmonthstr)
    ylabel.pack()
    mlabel.pack()


title = Label(root, text="\/\/\!!DOG AGE CALCULATOR!!\/\/\\")
yentry = Entry(root)
mentry = Entry(root)
getagebutton = Button(root, text="Get Dog Age", command=getAge)
yentry.insert(0, "Dog's Age In Years")
mentry.insert(0, "Dog's Age In Months")
title.pack()
yentry.pack()
mentry.pack()
getagebutton.pack()
y = yentry.get()
m = mentry.get()
```

In this program, how do i fix the error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\name\PycharmProjects\DAC\maintmp.py", line 19, in getAge
    if(y == 1):
       ^
UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'y' where it is not associated with a value
```

(the file is maintmp.py)

Comment: The `y` in the function is now local and not assigned. Put `global y` at the top of the function to reference the global y value.

Comment: Better yet, `getAge()` might want to accept `y` as a parameter.

Comment: make y global in the function and the value that you will get is string so, you will have to change to condtion to `if y == "1" :`

Comment: `global` should be avoided as it leads to unmanageable and inflexible code. I have only used it once in >15 years of Python programming. Using `y` as a parameter and giving it back with `return` is a far better option.

Answer (score 1):

You should move the call to `y = yentry.get()` inside the `getAge()` function

```
def getAge():
    y = yentry.get()
    # Convert y
    if(y == 1):
        dy = int(15)
    elif(y == 2):
        dy = int(24)
    elif(y > 2):
        dy = int(((y-2)*5)+24)
    else:
        p = 2
    ...  # code omitted for brevity
```

You'll want to do a similar thing when `get`ting the value of `m`. This way, the values are fetched from the entries when they're needed and can be updated accordingly.

As it's currently written, you're calling `get()` on your `Entry` widgets immediately after declaring them, so `y` and `m` will both be equal to `None`

You're getting the error `UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'y' where it is not associated with a value` because you're trying to perform a comparison operation on `y` before it has any value (as far as `getAge` is concerned)

Also, unrelated to the error: the explicit conversions like `int(15)` are unnecessary. 15 is already an `int`eger. You can just do `dy = 15`, `dy = 24`, etc. Since `y` is a string, you can just do the conversion on `y` with `y = int(yentry.get())` (the same goes for `m`).

Then you don't need to worry about things like `float(m*1.25)` either, since any number multiplied by a `float` will return a `float`!

Comment: it still gives the error saying that '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
when I try to convert it to int, it says 'y' is an invalid keyword argument for int()

Comment: How are you using a keyword argument with `int`?

Comment: How and where are you performing the conversion?

Comment: @chepner also that...

Comment: def getAge():
    int(y = yentry.get())
    int(m = mentry.get())
    # Convert y
    if(y == 1):
        dy = int(15)
    elif(y == 2):
        dy = int(24)
    elif(y > 2):
        dy = int(((y-2)*5)+24)
    else:
        p = 2
......................................................

Comment: It's just `int(yentry.get())`. The only keyword argument `int` accepts is `base`.

Comment: @chepner is right - what you actually want is `y = int(yentry.get()`. The assignment is done *outside* the call to `int`.